# AngularJS 1.2 | ngAnimate | prevent animation programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

How can I disable the animation of ng-view programmatically in angular-1.2rc2?

I made some manipulation on the route service that re-locate the user by his authentication role, and I want to programmatically prevent it.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't animate on the first appearance. Check out my fiddle and the console output: http://jsfiddle.net/FBMMu/7/

Comment: I guess this issue came because I made some handling of authenticate in the route process... I change the question.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the CSS animation class from your ng-view element.